# Interceptor in Spring 5 WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I am using `Spring WebFlux` in my project. I want to create an interceptor to calculate the time taken by each API. In `Spring MVC` we have `HandlerInterceptor` which is not present in `spring-boot-starter-webflux`. I tried adding `spring-boot-starter-web` and wrote my interceptor but it didn't work. Here is the code:

```
@Component
public class TimeInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TimeInterceptor.class);

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    request.setAttribute("startTime", startTime);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    long totaltime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (long) request.getAttribute("startTime");
    request.setAttribute("totaltime", totaltime);
    logger.info("Logging total time" + totaltime);

}
...
...
```

I want to add similar functionality to my application and intercept time taken by each call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to handle a request when it starts and when it completes, you can use [WebFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebFilter.html).

Try something like this

```
@Component
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return chain.filter(exchange).doFinally(signalType -> {
            long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            exchange.getAttributes().put("totalTime", totalTime);
            System.out.println(totalTime);
        });
    }
}
```

When request processing starts all defined filters are called. Mono is returned from filter. It indicates when request processing is complete.

Answer (score 7):

There is no concept of `HandlerInterceptor` in Spring WebFlux, but you can use your own `WebFilter` for that instead.

The feature you're describing sounds a lot like the metrics support provided by Actuator and Micrometer. If you'd like to try it:

1. Add the actuator dependency to your project
2. Expose [the relevant endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints) (here, `metrics`)
3. Go to `"/actuator/metrics` and select the metric for server HTTP requests (see [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics-web-flux)).

Micrometer offers way more and helps you to get your metrics right, like: taking into account GC pauses when measuring time, providing histograms/percentiles/..., and more.

Note: adding `spring-boot-starter-web` to your application will turn it into a Spring MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following project as dependency as jar / ant / maven / gradle

https://github.com/TurquoiseSpace/spring-webflux-http-interceptor

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.TurquoiseSpace</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webflux-http-interceptor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

It provides `ReactiveApiInterceptor` which is a custom implementation of `WebFilter`

Answer (score 0):

If required, you can override `ReactiveApiInterceptor` as well, to add your own custom logic, besides having the default logic, by calling

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
    // Your custom implementation, when api is hit and the request lands
    super.filter(serverWebExchange, webFilterChain)
        .doFinally(signalType -> {
            // Your custom implementation, when request-response exchange gets completed
        });
}
```