# #How can Achieve Interceptor in Spring Webflux to validate headers?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

added Interceptor and validating headers in `prehandle()` method of HandlerInterceptor interface and then with the help of `WebMvcConfigurer` interface adding this intercept and if success we are passing the control to the base url Controller class. Else it will return `false` and will not passing to the Controller class.

Same thing how we can achieve in Spring WebFlux ? in WebFlux there is similar interface like `WebFluxConfigurer` , but here is no such method add interceptor?

Also with the help of `RouterFunction` in WebFlux we can route , but how we can check and validate the headers in common section like `HandlerInterceptor` in Spring Mvc?**

Here is the below code snippet in Spring MVC :

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {   

@Autowired
CommonInterceptor CommonInterceptor;

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
registry.addInterceptor(CommonInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/v1/**");
}


 @Component
public class CommonInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommonInterceptor.class);

@Autowired
private CommonRequest CommonRequest;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws CommonException {
    String tenantContext = request.getHeader(CommonFrameworkConstants.TENANT_CONTEXT);
    String authToken = request.getHeader(CommonFrameworkConstants.AUTHORIZATION);
    LOGGER.trace("Handling Request for Tenant Context {}", tenantContext);
    CommonHeader CommonHeader = new CommonHeader(authToken, tenantContext);
    CommonRequest.setCommonHeader(commonHeader);
    CommonRequest.setUserName("api");
    return true;
}
 }
```

Comment: Have you seen the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091717/interceptor-in-spring-reactor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interceptor in spring reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091717/interceptor-in-spring-reactor)