# Spring-Webflux: Add jaeger traceId to log via MDC

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-webflux, jaeger, mdc

I use `Sping-Webflux` and want to automatically add `jaeger` traceId into my `@Slf4j` log.

I have an appender in my `logback.xml` with `%X{traceId}` pattern like this

```
<Pattern>
     %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %X{traceId} -2048msg%n
</Pattern>
```

Following to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56784776/4003272) answer on a similiar topic I have created a custom web filter where I added `traceId` into `MDC`:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final Tracer tracer;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        SpanContext spanContext = tracer.activeSpan().context();
        MDC.put("traceId", spanContext.toTraceId());
        return chain
            .filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it seems it works. But I have doubts that this solution is correct. I do not understand how a static `MDC.put` can handle simultaneously multiple different log events if they happen at the same time? When I put `traceId` into `MDC` will it affect all logs or only the required log which is linked to the web request?

Comment: MDC stores the key/values per thread context and a request is handle by a single thread.

Comment: Does it mean that every web request has it own MDC?

Comment: it means that you cant use MDC in webflux since MDC stores its value in ThreadLocal, and Webflux is thread agnostic meaning that you need to use the reactive context if you want this value to logged deeper into your application

Comment: I tried this `return chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(context -> context.put("traceId", spanContext.toTraceId()))` but it does not work: `%X{traceId}` stays undefined in the log pattern.

Comment: It looks like logback xml pattren variables do not see anything from reactive `context`.

Comment: logback has no idea of the reactive context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this very helpful [article](https://habr.com/ru/company/cft/blog/647479/) on habr. I followed the solution described in the article and realized the following:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final Tracer tracer;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(exchange)
                .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> {
                    SpanContext spanContext = tracer.activeSpan().context();
                    MDC.put("traceId", spanContext.toTraceId());
                })
                .doFinally(signalType -> {
                    MDC.remove("traceId");
                });
    }
}
```

As described in the article that solution has a limitation: it will not work if you will operate manually with a new thread creation - for example when using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`. This case is covered in the chapter "Дополнение" via `Schedulers.onScheduleHook`.

There is also an official solution from projectreactor faq on how to handle mdc for logging. You will find it [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.mdc). This solution is different from the habr article as it requires extra code and explicit set of `contextWrite` everytime you want to log the event.

Firstly, you introduce this helper function

```
public static <T> Consumer<Signal<T>> logOnNext(Consumer<T> logStatement) {
    return signal -> {
        if (!signal.isOnNext()) return;
        Optional<String> toPutInMdc = signal.getContext().getOrEmpty("traceId");

        toPutInMdc.ifPresentOrElse(tpim -> {
        try (MDC.MDCCloseable cMdc = MDC.putCloseable("traceId", tpim)) {
            logStatement.accept(signal.get());
        }
    },
    () -> logStatement.accept(signal.get()));
    };
}
```

Secondly, everytime you log something you need to call explicitly `logOnNext` and put `traceId` into reactive context:

```
@GetMapping("/byPrice")
public Flux<Restaurant> byPrice(@RequestParam Double maxPrice) {    
    return restaurantService.byPrice(maxPrice))
        .doOnEach(logOnNext(r -> LOG.debug("found restaurant {}", r.getName())))
        .contextWrite(Context.of("traceId", traceId));
}
```